# How can I make pagination size changable from admin in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

Currently I use django-constance, which gives me a fields in admin with configurable values.
And then I do this:

```
from constance import config

def get_page_pagination_with_custom_page_size(size):
    class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
        page_size = size

    return CustomPagination


class ArticleListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleListSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ArticleListFilterSet
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    pagination_class = get_page_pagination_with_custom_page_size(config.article_pagination)
```

With this I can change config.article_pagination from admin to alter pagination, but in order to apply all changes I need to restart server. How can I make my view class to be dynamic and catch all changes "on fly"?